# IN Clause selects all variables

Tags: mysql

When I run this procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER IN (6,192)
```

It retrieves rows where TAGS_COUNTER = 6 OR 192

How do I retrieve the rows from 'photo' where TAGS_COUNTER = 6 **AND** 192?

Corrected: the IN for ALL

Comment: have you tried to replace ALL with IN?

Comment: Personally I would do it `WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 6 AND photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 192`

Comment: When I use the AND clause it doesn't return any rows even though I'm positive it exists. The problem I think there is that there is one photo row, but 2 separate rows for photo_selectedTags (one being 6 and one being 192)

Comment: @supertopi thanks, that was my mistake when I posted the question. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is this:

```
SELECT PHOTO_COUNTER
FROM photo_selectedTags 
WHERE TAGS_COUNTER in (6, 192)
group by PHOTO_COUNTER
having count(distinct TAGS_COUNTER) = 2 --2 matches # of items in IN clause
```

You can then do this to get the rest of the columns:

```
SELECT *
from PHOTO_COUNTER 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
where photo.COUNTER in (
    SELECT PHOTO_COUNTER
    FROM photo_selectedTags 
    WHERE TAGS_COUNTER in (6,192)
    group by PHOTO_COUNTER
    having count(distinct TAGS_COUNTER) = 2 --2 matches # of items in IN clause
) a
```

Comment: when I run this query, it selects all the photos and all their tags where that tag is equal to 6 or 192. Code `SELECT *
FROM photo
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
where photo.COUNTER in (
    SELECT PHOTO_COUNTER
    FROM photo_selectedTags 
    WHERE TAGS_COUNTER in (6,192)
    group by PHOTO_COUNTER
    having count(distinct TAGS_COUNTER = 2)
)`

Comment: rock on! now, it selects every tag so photos that have 4 tags have four rows, how would I go about only returning the unique photo rows? (if that makes sense)

Comment: Just remove the left join (and `ON` clause) to the `photo_selectedTags` table in the topmost query.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Now that i understand what you want and DB structure, try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 6 AND photo_id IN
(SELECT photo_id FROM photoSELECT * FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 192)
```

I don't know if `photo_id` is an actual field of your table, but try to adapt it to your structure

Obviously in the first `SELECT` don't insert `PHOTO_COUNTER` because i'll be always the same value and it haven't much sense.

Comment: TAGS_COUNTER can be multiple items because can be multiple rows. There is one photo row but multiple tags (or keywords) associated with it.

Comment: @JesseClark Reading your third comment under your question, I suppose that i'am right.

Comment: @CAbbott : yes, i perfectly know it. But i suppose that the question itself haven't sense.

Comment: The DB has three tables; one for the photo, one for the tags and one that links the two together (photo_selectedTags). Was there a better way to set up the tables so that photo could have multiple tags?

Comment: @JesseClark Ok, so i suppose that you want something like what i do in my edit

Comment: When I do this, I get the error : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @JesseClark : do you change it in agreement with your db's table?

Comment: yes, I updated it to reflect my column names: 
`SELECT * FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 6 AND COUNTER IN
(SELECT * FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 192)`

Comment: @JesseClark You can't do something like that. You have to follow the query that i gave you, because if you do (in the second select) `SELECT *` you don't select a list of value (from a column) but a list of record. And this is wrong. Moreover, i suppose that you don't want to see if `COUNTER` isn't into the second query, but a value like an `id` or something like that. Please, follow my SQL or provide us your column name.

Comment: okay I see; on line 5 above, there was an extra select. The following does work: `SELECT * FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 6 AND COUNTER IN
(SELECT COUNTER FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
WHERE photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 192)` Thank you.

Comment: @JesseClark : and is exactly what i told you in my answer (with different fields, but same results)

Comment: What are you going to do when there are 10 items in the list? Or 100?

Comment: @RedFilter that is a great question; would there have been a better way to organize my tables to accomplish this easier?

Comment: @JesseClark No, your schema makes perfect sense. I was not-so-subtly suggesting that my approach is more practical in that regard.

Comment: @RedFilter : in what list? The first corrisponding on the first query, or the second one?

Comment: @RedFilter : I suppose that your query do the same.

Comment: @RedFilter : So i don't understand what you mean with "for each ID"

Comment: @RedFilter : If you - let's say - want that "TAGS_COUNTER" can have 10 or something like that, possibile values I say: "yes, your solution is better than mine". But I answered at a definite question with a finite possibilities. And the answer is good.

Comment: @RedFilter : are we there for discuss about copy/paste error? If yes, I absolutely not understand S.O. purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use 2 joins

```
SELECT *
FROM photo

JOIN photo_selectedTags as photo_selectedTags6 -- this join restricts to 'photo.COUNTER' whic have TAGS_COUNTER = 6
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags6.PHOTO_COUNTER
AND photo_selectedTags6.TAGS_COUNTER = 6

JOIN photo_selectedTags as photo_selectedTags192 -- this join restricts to 'photo.COUNTER' whic have TAGS_COUNTER = 192
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags192.PHOTO_COUNTER
AND photo_selectedTags192.TAGS_COUNTER = 192
```

Also would be possible to achive it with analytical functions (if supported by your DB)

```
-- This one works on teradata. Something similar should work on oracle. Don't know about others
SELECT *
FROM photo 
LEFT JOIN photo_selectedTags
ON photo.COUNTER = photo_selectedTags.PHOTO_COUNTER
QUALIFY max(case when photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 6 then 1 end) over (partition by photo.COUNTER) = 1
AND max(case when photo_selectedTags.TAGS_COUNTER = 192 then 1 end) over (partition by photo.COUNTER) = 1
```

If you have many values in the list (in addition to 192,6), then this might be possible solution

```
SELECT *
FROM photo
JOIN
(
    SELECT PHOTO_COUNTER, count(distinct TAGS_COUNTER) cnt
    FROM photo_selectedTags
    WHERE TAGS_COUNTER in (192,6)
    HAVING cnt = 2 -- adjust this according to the number of different values
) as pht
ON photo.COUNTER = pht.PHOTO_COUNTER
```

In subquery only PHOTO_COUNTERs are left which have both (192 and 6), then this is joined

Comment: Thank you! The first example works, the second has in issue with the QUALIFY line. Is there a way to combine these into one join or does it have to be separated out? I'd imagine this could blog down if I'm looking for more than 2 tags.